# Cannot find the interlop type that matches the embedded type ' ' are you missing an assembly reference... ERROR

Tags: vb.net

here is my code:

```
Imports System.Windows.Forms
```

Imports Microsoft.Office.Tools.Word
Imports Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word

Public Class Form1

```
'Imports Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim openfile As OpenFileDialog = New OpenFileDialog()

    If openfile.ShowDialog() Then
        Dim file As String = openfile.FileName
        Dim outfile As String = "C:\\file.pdf"
        Dim extension As String = System.IO.Path.GetExtension(file)
        If extension = ".doc" Or extension = ".docx" Then
            Dim app As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application = New Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application()
            Dim doc As Microsoft.Office.Tools.Word.Document = Nothing
            doc = app.Documents.Open(file, Type.Missing, False)
            doc.ExportAsFixedFormat(outfile, Word.WdExportFormat.wdExportFormatPDF)
            doc.Close(False, Type.Missing, Type.Missing)
            app.Quit(False, False, False)
            System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(app)


        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

End Class

i am trying to make a program which had the adobe pdf reader, you open a word file and it converts to pdf and shows it in the reader.

But i am getting this error: Cannot find the interlop type that matches the embedded type ' ' are you missing an assembly reference... ERROR. I have put embed interlop type to false. I am not sure what to do. Please help.

Thanks in advance.

- i researched a lot but i couldnt find anything so then I came here.

Comment: please help me! i need to do this ASAP :(

Comment: This MSDN blog describes three related error messages and how to solve them: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vbteam/2010/06/11/troubleshooting-errors-when-embedding-type-information-doug-rothaus/

Comment: i dont really understand that. i saw it already.

Comment: the error is on this line btw : doc.ExportAsFixedFormat(outfile, Word.WdExportFormat.wdExportFormatPDF) for wdexportformat.